# Database for NLP project

Tags: python, mysql, mongodb, nlp, bigdata

Can someone advise on what database is better for storing textual information such as part of speech sequences, dependencies, sentences used in NLP project written in python. Now this information is stored in files and they need to be parsed every time in order to extract the mentioned blocks which are used as an input for next processing stage. 
Options considered  - MongoDB, Cassandra and MySQL. Are NoSQL databases better in this type of application.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This really depends on what exactly you are storing and which operations you will perform on this data.

SQL vs. NoSQL is a very fundamental decision and no one can give you a good advice here. If your data fits relational model well, then, SQL (PostgreSQL or MySQL) is your choice. If your data is more like documents, use MongoDB.

That said, just recently I made a search engine. We had to store indexed pages (raw text), the same text but tokenized and some additional metadata. MongoDB performed really well.